# How I remove the comma separator in integer edit input?

Tags: pega

I want to remove the comma separator in the inter-input field using edit input how I achieve that?

[image]

The above image displays the standard format.
The expecting Number Format (without comma) - 1234

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using `Integer` input field UI control. Even if you write a `Edit Input` rule, it is going to display a comma separator on the UI if the `Separator` is marked as `Yes` in the `Presentation` tab of the input field control settings.

Go to the `Presentation` tab of the input control and mark `Separator` as `No`.

[Integer Properties - Presentation tab](https://docs.pega.com/user-experience-theme-ui-kit/86/integer-properties-presentation-tab)